# Syntax for calling templated method

Tags: c++, templates

I'm wondering what's the proper syntax for calling template method given as:

```
struct print_ch {
    print_ch(char const& ch) : m_ch(ch) { }
    ~print_ch() { }
    template<typename T>
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << static_cast<T>(m_ch) << std::endl;
    }
    private:
    char m_ch;
};
```

I came up with sth like this:

```
print_ch printer('c');
printer.operator()<int>();
```

And it seems to work (GCC 4.5), but when I use it inside another templated method, e.g.:

```
struct printer {

    typedef int print_type;

    template<typename T_functor>
    static void print(T_functor& fnct) {
        fnct.operator()<print_type>();
    }

};
```

Compilation fails with `error: expected primary-expression before '>' token`. Any idea to get it right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's much cleaner to just create a regular function. Operators should be used sparingly and when appropriate.

Comment: @JoshD thanks, seems you're right, I'll need to reconsider this

Comment: Indeed, overloading `operator()` doesn't make sense here, because it can't be called with the same syntax as a regular function, which completely defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler explicitly that the `operator()` of the templated `fnct` is itself a template:

```
fnct.template operator()<print_type>();
```

If you don't specify this with the `template` keyword the compiler will assume that `operator()` is just a normal method, not a template.

Answer (score 2):

Since T_functor is itself a template, the compiler (or parser) assumes to know nothing about it's members, so you have to explicetly tell it you are calling a template methode using:

```
        fnct.template operator()<print_type>();
```